# BarChart: First Bin centered at 0 instead of 1

Tags: graphics, histograms, charts

I want to plot an overlapped graphic comparing the experimental and theoretical data of the number of counts in a given time (beta decay), so I show them in a histogram.

Because of sometimes the number of counts is 0, the experimental histogram has a bin centered at 0.

```
v = ListPlot[{{Around[M, S], 34/2}}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Thick, Black}];
l = Graphics[{Dashed, Thick, {Line[{{M, 0}, {M, 34}}], Line[{{M - S, 34/2}, {M + S, 34/2}}]}}];
h = Histogram[t, Frame -> True,  FrameLabel -> {"Cuentas / 20 s", "Frecuencia"},  FrameStyle ->    Directive[GrayLevel[0], 20, FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12",     AbsoluteThickness[1.0`]],  ImageSize -> 600,  FrameTicks -> {{Table[i, {i, 0, 35, 5}],      None}, {Table[i, {i, 0, 8}], None}},[![enter image description here][1]][1]  PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 8.5}, Automatic}]
m1 = Show[h, l, v]
```

[image]

The problem appears when I build the theortical plot. I have a list of calculated heights of the bins (included 0 counts), so I use a `BarChart`

```
B = BarChart[Fteor, BarSpacing -> None, Frame -> True,   FrameLabel -> {"Cuentas / 20 s", "Frecuencia"},   FrameStyle -> 
Directive[GrayLevel[0], 20, FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", 
 AbsoluteThickness[1.0`]],   ImageSize -> 600];
A = ListPlot[{{Around[M, J], Max[Fteor]/2}}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Thick, Black}];
G = Graphics[{Dashed, Black, Thick, Line[{{M, 0}, {M, Max[Fteor]}}]}];[![enter image description here][1]][1]

m2 = Show[B, A, G]
```

[image]

And if I combine them:

```
Show[m1,m2]
```

[image]

As you can see, the theoretical `BarChart` put the first bin (0 events) at position 1. I also have added other graphics to view the experimental and theoretical standard deviation and mean of distribution (Variables S, J, M, respectively) so I don't want to edit the rest of elements, only `BarChart` (for simplicity).

Is there a simple way to tell Mathematica to put the first bin of a `BarChart` centered at 0 instead of 1?

P.S.: I have already seen solutions of creating Rectangles with given height and position, but I am looking for a simple solution with `BarChart` (if it is posible)

Thanks!
Dani

Comment: An alternative would be to use `Histogram` instead of `BarChart` - this way, you get the same look for free. You can supply the data to `Histogram` as `WeightedData[xlist,ylist]`, where `xlist` is the bin position, and `ylist` is the bin height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** You can also use `Method` suboptions `"BarStartingValue"` and `"FixedBarSpacing"`:

```
barheights = {2, 1, 3};

Show[BarChart[barheights, BarSpacing -> 0, Axes -> False, 
  Method -> {"BarStartingValue" -> -.5, "FixedBarSpacing" -> True}], 
 ListLinePlot[{{1, 3}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can post-process the `BarChart` output to change the coordinates of `Rectangle`s:

```
barheights = {2, 1, 3};

bc = Show[BarChart[barheights , BarSpacing -> 0, Axes -> False], 
  ListLinePlot[{{1, 3}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
  Frame -> True]
```

[image]

```
bc /. RectangleBox[a_, b_, c___] :>  RectangleBox[{-1, 0} + a, {-1, 0} + b, c]
```

[image]

**Note:** In versions 9.0 and older, replace `RectangleBox` with `Rectangle`.

An alternative approach using `Histogram` with `barheights&` as the height specification:

```
binning = {0.5, 3.5, 1};
Show[Histogram[{1}, binning, barheights &], 
 ListLinePlot[{{1, 3}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
   Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

You can modify the binning specification to move the rectangles:

```
Show[Histogram[{1}, binning - {1, 1, 0}, barheights &], 
 ListLinePlot[{{1, 3}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
   Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I personally used the aproach with `Histogram` `BarHeight &`. Very simple solution!

Comment: @DaniDoménech, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach using [`Histogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html) and [`WeightedData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html), as described in the comments:

```
barheights = {2, 1, 3};

Show[
 Histogram[
  WeightedData[Range@Length@barheights - 1, barheights],
  Length@barheights
 ],
 ListLinePlot[{{1, 3}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image]